# Firebase Remote Config - Cannot create conditions on the console

Tags: firebase-remote-config

I've created a project in Firebase and have added apps to it, but on the Remote Config screen, I don't see the expected **Conditions** tab next to the Parameters tab and also I am getting a message **"You've already provided a value for every defined condition "**

This does not align with the documentation

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a personalisation first.

[image]

Fill out create personalisation form then create a new condition.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The conditions tab will appear after creating the first condition.

[image]

Done :)

Comment: This is not necessarily correct. You don't need to rope in personalization for this. It just means  that he doesn't have any predefined conditions. he can just "create" a new one

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use 'Personalisation' for this. Just tap on 'Conditions' tab in Firebase and add any condition you like (app version, device locale, country etc).

These condition can then be used for any value inside the 'Parameters' tab.